# How can I parse this string of xml?

Tags: javascript, string, parsing

I'm struggling to remove the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>` of this string.

```js
var string = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='no'?><svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg...'"

console.log(string.split("?>")[1])
```

of course the string is bigger in reality but it's not useful to have it.

So how could I remove only the `<?xml...>` ?

[EDIT] I added a split but I'm not sure it's a professional way to remove the first tag

Comment: Its XML not HTML, the way to parse it is with an XML Parser, or if you truly just want to chop it off: `string = string.substring(54);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various ways to do this, but given that the part you want to exclude is static, this will do it:

```js
var string = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='no'?><svgxmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg...'";

string = string.replace("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='no'?>","");

console.log(string)
```

Comment: Simple and effective

Comment: Ok I'll do it like this so :)

Comment: Although, if it is static, it might be easier just to use `.slice()` instead of `.replace()`. As in: `string = string.slice(54)`;

Comment: @LambdaNinja As I said, there are various ways to do it, but really, this took all of 7 seconds to write and doesn't perform any better/worse than any of the other techniques. Pretty easy.

Answer (score 2):

Use regex and replace(requres less keystrokes *_* )

```js
var string = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='no'?><svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg...'"

console.log(string.replace(/<\?xml.*\?>/, ''))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var string = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='no'?><svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg...'";
var charIdx = str.indexOf('?>')+2;
string = string.substr(charIdx);
```